# update object one by one of asyn

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mean-stack

For my app, there are matches and schedules. My idea is simple, but i cannot find a way to do it with angularjs for its asyn nature.

for matches, there are so called [a, b, c] three matches as an example.
for schedules, there are more than three resources such as [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7].

I would like to pair matches with available schedules so that [a1, b2, c4] with unique pairing.

I just wonder why the follow code doesn't work:

```
            for (var u in matches){
                var matchDefer = $q.defer();
                var matchPromise = matchDefer.promise;

                var match = matches[u]
                var schedule = schedules[u];

                Matches.get({matchId: match._id}, function(matchResponse){
                    console.info('schedule', schedule);
                    matchResponse.AddSchedule(schedule, matchDefer);
                });

                matchPromise.then(function(result){
                    console.info('result', result);
                }, function(reason){
                    console.info('reason', reason);
                });
            }
```

And the following code is in the match service:

```
  Matches.prototype.AddSchedule = function(schedule, defer) {
    this.schedule = schedule._id;
    this.$update(function(matchResponse){
        schedule.match = matchResponse._id;
        schedule.$update(function(scheduleResponse){
            defer.resolve(scheduleResponse._id);
        });
    });
```

Could anyone help me even just give me some hints to do it, thanks!

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by 'it doesn't work'? Is there an error? What is printed in the console? What were you expecting?

Comment: sorry, just forgot to provide such information. The three matches are all assigned for one schedule instead of three different schedules. Therefore, i guess it is about some timing issue.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but the code you provided seems to be doing exactly that: it takes the first match and pairs it with the first schedule, then takes the second match and pairs it with the second schedule, then takes the third match and pairs it with the third schedule. That's all. The asynchronicity is handled perfectly well. If at the end 'the three matches are all assigned for one schedule' then this code works, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Did you sort that out? Or you still need some help?